# How do you split a paragraph or page into 2 variables using TCL?

Tags: regex, string, tcl

I know you can find a string and place everything after it into a variable using TCL and regex like the following

```
regexp "Shipping \(\[^\f]+)" $VarWithWholePage match shipinfo;
```

But is it possible to place everything before the string into a variable?

For example.

> Sentence number 1.
>   Sentence number 2.
>   Sentence number 3.
>   Sentence number 4.
>   Shipping
>   Sentence number 5.

My example would place "Sentence number 5." into `shipinfo`, but I would like to be able to place

> Sentence number 1.
>   Sentence number 2.
>   Sentence number 3.
>   Sentence number 4.

into another variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp "\(.*\)Shipping \(\[^\f]+)" $VarWithWholePage match before after;
```

should put the text before "Shipping" in `before` and the part after in `after`.

P.S. I am not sure why you are using `^\f`, but if you have a good reason you can use it also in the first subexpression.

Comment: Using \f will allow it to read multiple sentences up to the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks this worked and accomplished exactly what I wanted

Comment: Frank, if this answer does exactly what you want you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible to place everything before the string into a variable?

The simplest way to do this is to get `regexp` to tell you the indices of the match instead of the matched substring. You can then use `string range` to get the parts you want.

```
regexp -indices "Shipping \(\[^\f]+)" $VarWithWholePage match shipinfo
```

At this point, `match` and `shipinfo` will have pairs of numbers indicating exactly where the match happened within the input string. *If* the match succeeded.

```
# Now we can get the bits before (and after) the match with simple operations
set beforeMatch [string range $VarWithWholePage 0 [expr {[lindex $match 0] - 1}]]
set afterMatch [string range $VarWithWholePage [expr {[lindex $match 1] + 1}] end]

# Convert the string ranges into the matched substrings so that your code still works
set match [string range $VarWithWholePage {*}$match]
set shipinfo [string range $VarWithWholePage {*}$shipinfo]
```

*Footnote:* your RE would be idiomatically written as `{Shipping ([^\f]+)}` as it's usually a very good idea to put regular expressions in braces. It combats backslash-itis.

Comment: Thanks. A little overkill, but nice to know for when I need in the future. Thanks for the tip on the braces.